# Drupal: Custom CSS not integrating

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I recently started using Drupal for a new website I am trying to build. Front-end is normally what I focus on and I'd use external services to integrate backend functions. In this (and potentially from now on) I want to start using Drupal.  Now, I have installed a bootstrap module and want to start adding own css from there but I can't seem to figure out how/where. I can't do it straight into the bootstrap style files so I - apparently - need to create my own theme and place css files in there. This is what I have done so far:

1: Have my css file with the code.
2: Created a new folder next to the bootstrap folder in sites/all/themes.
3: Put the css file in there.
4: Created an my_theme.info file.

But it is not resulting in any changes on the website (it also does not show up in the source code) most likely because it is not being called by Drupal. How can I make sure Drupal calls my css code?

Thanks in advance and take care!

Comment: how are you including your css file in your info file. Have you cleared the theme cache?

Comment: Go to "Appearance" from back-end menu. Do you see your theme there? Did you set it as default one? You should do that.

Comment: this tutorial can helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lc2c4bHHRZg

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the input. I tried all of that but somehow it just did not read my theme. Couldn't put my finger on where the error was and decided to start with an external theme. I'll potentially come back to this at a later moment. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is DRUPAL 7 (Drupal 8 uses yaml)

1. Create a subtheme of the theme you choose.
2. In the `YOURTHEME.info` you add a line like `stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css`
3. In `YOURTHEME/css` directory, here you can start writing your css rules in the file `style.css`
4. Make sure caching is off or else you will not see your css being updated.

Comment: Outside of this, there is nothing that needs to be done? Like linking the new theme into drupal? The location of the folder itself should provide that?

Comment: Yes, step 1 is another topic within itself, but once you learn how to set up a subtheme (I assume you will use bootstrap) then you can do the other steps. [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010) here is a resource to create a subtheme of bootstrap

Comment: Enable your subtheme